# .htaccess non-www to www URL Redirect Erases any URL path beyond base url

Tags: url, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

When visitors go, to say,:

http://**website.com/dir/dir2/file.html**

My re-write clears the path beyond the base url and redirects them to the home page with www. in the front:

http://**www.website.com/**

How can I prevent the stripping from occurring and sending visitors to the homepage instead of their requested url? FYI, the URLs in question DO exist.

Thanx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include the file/path info on the end of the rewrite like this:

```
RewriteCond     %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\.website\.com [NC]
RewriteCond     %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
RewriteRule     ^/(.*)         http://www.website.com/$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: I dropped in the rewrites after: RewriteRule .* index.php [L] but it's still redirecting to the base url. Is that RewriteRule causing the fuss? Should the code you suggested go before the index.php RewriteRule? Thanks

Comment: This should always be your first rule. It is at the top of all my other rules because it needs to come first. Once the site has redirected to the fully-qualified domain, the conditions in this first rule will no longer be met so it will be bypassed and the rest of your rules will take effect.

Comment: Rick, in response to your answer below (since I can't comment on it), I actually don't remember what the second line is for. It may be optional as you have suggested. The way the regex reads, it is looking for a non-empty HTTP_HOST -- I'm not really sure when that condition would be true. I just know this set of 3 lines has worked well for a number of sites I oversee for quite a few years.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, DWK!  Cheers, Rick

Answer (score 3):

FYI, this is for a Magento site.

In .htaccess, after

```
#RewriteBase /magento/
```

After it I placed on their own lines:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.website\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

And it works. Dad with kids also had it right, just don't know what the second line was for.

Comment: ...no he doesn't! that $ on the first line is quite hand too!

Answer (score 1):

Most people need `RewriteBase` set, so try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?:www\.your-live-domain\.com|staging\.domain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteRule .* http://www.your-live-domain.com/$0 [L,R=301]
```

Use 301 to make it permanent